# Toggle all the sudden won't work, JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I've helped/worked with a website project hte last month but is now stuck since the .toggle function for the menu don't work as expected.

I made a fiddle of the full menu [here](https://jsfiddle.net/daPerley/sb2jaok9/4/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.menuD').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('.mennu').toggleClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

(This is my first time using fiddle so I hope I've enterd everything the right way, as I understood it as I don't have to include the "head" area.)

I can't really figure why it ain't working since I did a similar solution for my own page last year that works and validates perfectly. Javascript aren't my strongest language so some help to find the problem(s) would be appriciated.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sb2jaok9/5/)

Comment: Oh, that's great, big thank you, have to compare them to see where I lacked.

Comment: check this part `jQuery(this).parent().next().toggleClass('active');` the menu you want to toggle is not the element you are clicking you need to reference it correctly

Comment: Ok, then I should read some more on referencing, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo :

```
jQuery('.mennu').toggleClass('active');
```

must be

```
jQuery('.menu').toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeoutMenu = null;
$('.trigger').on("click", function() {
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutMenu);
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
}, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.menu, .menu ul {
        list-style:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .menu a {
        float:left;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000;
    }
    .menu li:hover > a {
        color:#666;
    }
    .menu ul {
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        top:25px;
        z-index:1;
        background:#666;
    }
    .menu li:hover > ul {
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    .menu ul a {
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
        text-transform:none;
    }
    .menu ul a:hover {
        background-color:lightgray;
    }
.trigger:hover .dropdown,
.trigger.clicked .dropdown {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a class="trigger">MENU</a>

        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```